# Rsyslog Discarding Unwanted Messages

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

Once again, i found that Rsyslog is not as flexible as i expected...

My application logs to **LOCAL5.*** ( depending on the severity )

I would like to see on my centralized log server only **LOCAL5.WARNING** and above

I assumed and tested

```
local5.info            ~
```

However this means block **LOCAL5.INFO** and ABOVE

How do i make it block **LOCAL5.INFO** and BELOW ???

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems

```
if $syslogfacility-text == 'local5' and $syslogseverity >= '5' then ~
```

did the trick...

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.